# Can’t change my name in Google Accounts

Tags: google-account, profile

When I go to my main Google account to update my name (which I've never done since I set it up) it is not changeable. The comment below my last name says

> This setting can't be changed for your account.

I've seen some other similar questions and people say to go into settings and change “send mail as”—that does NOT solve the problem.

I have a second Google account and am able to change my name in that account so it doesn't make sense that I can’t also change it in my main account.

NO, I do not have a Google+ account nor do I want one.  Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Is your google account an individual / consumer account or it's a managed / Google Apps account?

Comment: I have the same problem with my university's domain account, which appears to use enterprise Google Apps.